# Filtering Dates : TypeError at / expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make a filter based on dates for scheduled events. I want items that happened between 60 days ago and that are scheduled 60 days from now. So the start of the range is today - 60 days and the end of the range is today + 60 days. I haven't used Django in a long time and I don't know if this is a new issue with the current version and the auto_now and auto_add_now or if the issue is using DateField. I used DateField on the models because I don't care about the time and don't want these time fields added to the database. I want clean dates.

Index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
     <title>Document</title>
     <body>
         <div id=form>
            <select name="Title" id="title_box">
                {% for item in items %}
                    <option value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %} 
           </select>   
        </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations, models
import datetime

class Cycle(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, 
    blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, 
    blank=True, null=True)
```

I changed the field from DateField to DateTimeField and it made no difference, so I changed it back to `DateField`.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from .models import *
import datetime

def main(request):
    beginDate = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=60)
    stopDate = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=60)
    context = {
         "items": Cycle.objects.filter(start_date=[beginDate,stopDate])
    }
    return render (request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

I want to display the events that happened between 60 days ago and that will happen the next 60 days. The code I have now only reflects the start_date in the model. I'm just trying to take baby steps and figure out one and then use OR to get the other later. I imagine it would be something like:

```
"items": Cycle.objects.filter(start_date=[beginDate,stopDate] | end_date=[beginDate, stopDate])
```

Anyways, the error I'm getting is:

TypeError at /expected string or bytes-like object

I think the error is with :

```
context = {
         "items": Cycle.objects.filter(start_date=[beginDate,stopDate])
    }
```

I printed the "beginDate" and it gave me 2018-11-09, which is correct for the range I want. I used `type` to see if it would help me figure out the mismatch and got `<class 'datetime.date'>` . I'm thinking now that maybe it doesn't match with the models.py, but I'm not sure if it is the case and if it is how to make them match. After reading a few posts I also tried using `timezone.now()` and `date.today()` for the `beginDate` and the `stopDate`, but got errors that said that date and timezone were not defined. I also made sure to use 'makemigrations' and 'migrate'.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter on a date range like you're doing here you need to change your filter arguments to use `__range`. By doing `start_date=` like you have there, you're looking for a value for `start_date` that matches exactly e.g. `start_date= beginDate`

You've also got a `|` operator in there. If you want to do a `start_date` in a range, and `end_date` in a range, you need to change that for a `,`.

```
Cycle.objects.filter(
    start_date__range=[beginDate, stopDate],
    end_date__range=[beginDate, stopDate]
)
```

If you're looking to say `start_date` between dates OR `end_date` between dates, then you need to use django `Q` objects.

```
from django.db.models import Q


Cycle.objects.filter(
    Q(start_date__range=[beginDate, stopDate]) | Q(end_date__range=[beginDate, stopDate])
)
```

The documentations for [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) is worth a read.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked like a charm. I ended using the Q objects. Is that new to for the latest Django version? I don't remember ever seen it before. Anyways, thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @FranchescaYamiquemeimporta Q objects have been in Django for a long time, but they don't really get noticed until you start doing more complex queries. I've added a link to the docs for them.

Comment: @ markwalher_ Got it. Thanks again for your assistance.